# Certificate/SSL pinning with AFNetworking - How to trust all parents certificates if the child is trusted?

Tags: ios, ssl, ssl-certificate, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I want to only trust a specific certificate + all root certificates. For instance:

```
GeoTrust Global CA               <= Automatically trusted
    Google Internet Authority G2 <= Automatically trusted
        *.google.com             <= Trusted because in a .cer in the app bundle
```

But what happens now with AFNetworking 2.2.1 is this:

```
GeoTrust Global CA               <= Not trusted because not in the bundle
    Google Internet Authority G2 <= Not trusted because not in the bundle
        *.google.com             <= Trusted because in a .cer in the app bundle
```

How is it possible to accept root certificates as well?

Answer (score 2):

Your certificate was issued by Google Internet Authority G2 CA, and the root CA is GeoTrust Global CA, so the certificate should be trusted by the iOS. It is indeed.

You can check the "[List of available trusted root certificates](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5012)" here.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices/#//apple_ref/c/func/SecTrustEvaluate

> The SecTrustEvaluate function validates a certificate by verifying its signature plus the signatures of the certificates in its certificate chain, up to the anchor certificate, according to the policy or policies included in the trust management object.
>
> If some of the certificates needed to verify the leaf certificate are missing from the trust management object, then SecTrustEvaluate searches for certificates in the following locations:
>
> - In any keychains currently on the caller’s keychain search list (see SecTrustSetKeychains).
> - Any certificates previously provided by calling SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates.
> - In a system-provided set of keychains provided for this purpose.
> - Over the network if certain extensions are present in the certificate used to build the chain.

So, if the SecTrustEvaluate return errSecSuccess and the result is kSecTrustResultUnspecified/kSecTrustResultProceed, it already trust the certificate chain.

In your situation, the validatesCertificateChain was YES, so it compared each certificate data in the certificate chain with the certificate files in the bundle. Usually it's used to validate self-signed certificate. You should disable it.

Answer (score 1):

AFNetworking 2.1.0 added [certificate chain validation](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/2.1.0/AFNetworking/AFSecurityPolicy.h#L47), which defaults to YES (validate the chain). You can disable it:

```
// policy used by AFHTTPRequestOperation / AFHTTPRequestOperationManager
AFSecurityPolicy *securityPolicy = somePolicy; 
securityPolicy.validatesCertificateChain = NO;
```